# Excel: "Run-Time error -2147417848 (80010108)" Method 'Delete' of object 'Range' failed

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, conditional-formatting

I have a macro that deletes a selected table row in a protected sheet in Excel, and am receiving the error in the title whenever the code is run. This issue started occuring when I introduced 10 Conditional Format rules to the worksheet, and if I clear the worksheet of any conditional formats, I'm able to delete as many rows as I like. My code to delete the table row below, as well as where the debug is pointing to clear the error.

```
Sub DeleteRow()

    Application.EnableEvents = False    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheet1.Unprotect Password:="Password!"
    Dim rng As Range    
    On Error Resume Next
    With Selection.Cells(1)
        Set rng = Intersect(.EntireRow, ActiveCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Please select a valid table cell.", vbCritical
        Else
            rng.Delete xlShiftUp   'This is the line where the debug is pointing to
        End If
    End With
    Sheet1.Protect Password:="Password!"
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

*Update No #Ref! errors on any of my Conditional Format formulas. 
**Update I have about 10 Conditional Format formulas, with slight variations below.

```
=AND(COUNTIFS($E$14:$E$17,$E14,$J$14:$J$17,"Black")>1,$J14="Black")
=AND(COUNTIFS($E$14:$E$17,$E14,$J$14:$J$17,"White")>1,$J14="White")
=AND(COUNTIFS($E$14:$E$17,$E14,$J$14:$J$17,"Green")>1,$J14="Green")
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the conditional formatting is having a  ***#REF!*** error somewhere, thus Excel does not allow the deletion. To see all the formulas in the conditional formats, run this:

```
Sub ListAllConditionalFormat()

    Dim cf      As FormatCondition
    Dim ws      As Worksheet
    Dim l       As Long
    Dim rngCell As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("Report").Cells.Clear

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Debug.Print ws.Name

        For Each cf In ws.Cells.FormatConditions
            l = 1 + l
            With Worksheets("Report")
                Set rngCell = .Cells(l, 1)
                rngCell = cf.AppliesTo.Address
                rngCell.Offset(0, 1) = cf.Type
                rngCell.Offset(0, 2) = "'" & cf.Formula1
                rngCell.Offset(0, 3) = cf.Interior.Color
                rngCell.Offset(0, 4) = cf.Font.Name
                rngCell.Offset(0, 5) = ws.Name
                rngCell.Offset(0, 6) = "'" & cf.AppliesTo.AddressLocal
                rngCell.Offset(0, 7) = "'" & cf.Formula2
            End With
        Next cf
    Next ws
    Debug.Print "END!"

End Sub
```

Just make sure that you have a worksheet, named `Report`, where everything is empty. The information for the conditional formats would be there. Look for ***#REF!*** errors and fix them once you see them.

Comment: Hmmmm... I created tblReport worksheet, but nothing comes up when I run your code. I made sure that it was one the first worksheet, any thoughts?

Comment: @MSauce - see the code again and rename the table from `tblReport` to `Report`, I have edited it.

Comment: That worked, sadly no #REF! errors, the problem persists :(

Comment: @MSauce - any other errors? In general, before the line with the error, write `rng.Select: Stop` and it will stop. Then take a look at the conditional formatting on that range. I guess there should be something strange...

Comment: Nope, just the one I posted from my original question. I do have multiple Conditional formats of essentially the same formula, can that be an issue?=AND(COUNTIFS($E$14:$E$17,$E14,$J$14:$J$17,"Black")>1,$J14="Black")     Essentially that formula for 7 different colors, replace "Black" with "White, Orange, Green" etc. etc.

Comment: @MSauce - Idk, the formulas look ok. Probably the point is that you are deleting something between 14th and 17th row and the conditional formatting does not like it.

Comment: @MSauce - try to disable the events, before deleting - `Application.EnableEvents = False` and enable them after the deletion - `Application.EnableEvents = True`.

Comment: Didn't work either, I've edited my question to reflect the changes. I definitely appreciate your suggestions.